# How can I make a text box a choice field?

Tags: python, django, model

I want to display the choice field in forms.

This is my model but I am not able to see the select box, it displays as textarea.

```
SOURCE_CHOICES = Choices(
    ('var1', '1'),
    ('var2', '2')
)

source = models.TextField(choices=SOURCE_CHOICES, null=True, blank=True)
```

Do I need to put something in my form as well?

In my previous project I did the same thing. I defined everything in my model and saw the select box but not here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use `CharField` instead `TextField`:

```
source = models.CharField(choices=SOURCE_CHOICES, max_length=3, ... )
```

TextField is rendered always as TextArea.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#choices